# React native navigate to ID of specific post

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to navigate the same way you do with react-router.
I am fetching an API and display the results as cards, when you click a card, I need it to navigate to a specific ID based on the card selected.

```
<Route path='/item:id' component={item-details} />
```

and then on the card, you do this.`<Link to='item/:id' > Card...</Link>`

That's how you do it with react-router-dom...I need to archive the same with React Native.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org), it's the best solution for navigation for a RN app. It's not quite like React Router but RN requires a different method. In react-navigation, you declare your screens as 'navigators', e.g [stack navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/).

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1Component} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2Component} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

On each screen, a `navigation` prop is passed down. This has a lot of properties and functions but one is a function called `navigate`, which takes you to another screen in your stack. For example:

```
const Screen1Component = ({ navigation }) => (
  <View>
    // content 
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen2) })>Go to Screen2</TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
)
```

`navigate` also has a second parameter it can take called [screen params](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen). These are parameters you can pass between screens when you navigate. It's used like `navigation.navigate('Screen2, { id: '1234' })`.

In your Screen2 component, there will be a `route` prop, where you can then pick that param up and use it, for example:

```
const Screen2Component = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const { id } = route.params
  // do something with it, call api, pass to redux action,etc

  return ...
}
```

Hope that helps.